# Delay Shutdown in Android Programmatically

Tags: android

I have a shutdown receiver and in the event of a shutdown, I want to POST that to my server to track what time the device is shut down. The problem is that by the time the shutdown receiver is triggered, networking is already shut down so there is no way to send the information. I could store the time locally and send upon next bootup but it would be ideal if I could somehow pause the shutdown process until after the information is sent. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you could neither should to do it. Just keep it in SHaredPrefernces until next time.

Comment: If you already have a SQLite db, you could create a log table and log such events there.

Comment: @AlLelopath do you mean SQLite db locally? Because the POST request is getting processed on the server to go to MongoDB

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant locally. Then later, send the contents of the log table back to the server. That may not be what you need, though. Just throwing stuff out there.

Comment: you got the solution.? i also stuck on the same problem from a long time. please help me